# PseudoTTY executing commands programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pty

There is an open source Xcode project called "PseudoTTY" written in objective-c and I'm trying to find out how to execute commands programmatically.  When I compile the application, I get a nice little terminal window that does exactly what I want; except I have to manually type the command in.

What I want to do is programatically execute a command in the terminal, and be able to parse the results with my program.

Spots of interest are:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    const char * typein = [[event characters] UTF8String];

    [[pty_ masterFileHandle]
          writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:typein length:strlen(typein)]];
}
```

and

```
-(void) didRead: (NSNotification *)noty
{
    NSData * data = [[noty userInfo] objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];

    if ([data length] == 0)
        return; // end of file

    NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [self insertText:str];
```

Comment: @Carl I updated the question, I added the question.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is replace `typein` with a string of your choice and it will do what you want.  The output will be in `str` in the `didRead:` method.

```
char *myCommand = "ls";
[[pty_ masterFileHandle] writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:myCommand 
                                                  length:strlen(myCommand)]];
```

Comment: Looks interesting; I'll try it when I get a chance!

Comment: How do I tell the window to "push" the enter key so it will run the command?  Thanks!